# Regular expression in Java for matching series of integers

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in Java to match strings that look like

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

That is, a left parenthesis, followed by a nonzero amount of nonnegative integers (separated by a comma and then any amount of whitespace), and ending with a right parenthesis.

I've tried

```
 ([0-9]+,\s+)
```

Does anyone know how to write such a regular expression?

Comment: We defiantly know how too ... what have you tried ? follow this link and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html and then to come up with something before asking for help.

Comment: I tried this: ([0-9]+,\s+)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Also, use http://regex101.com/

Comment: @JasonMarkov please add it to the question and ask what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @JasonMarkov Also, show what actually happened when you tried it. Every question should show the code you used, the input, what you expected and what actually happened

Comment: Not a bad try... now add a `+` at the end and surround everything with escaped parens.

Comment: Now add *how* did you try it and what went wrong (did you get wrong results/errors?)

Comment: For help learning Regular Expressions check out [link](http://www.regexr.com/).  It's not my site but it has helped me understand and learn RegEx.

Comment: You are not backslashing the parentheses

Answer (score 4):

You can try this pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d+(,\\s*\\d+)*\\)");
```

`\\d`: a digit (`0` to `9`)

`\\s`: a whitespace character

`+`: one or more occurrences

`*`: zero or more occurrences

See  http://regex101.com/r/wT5wX7/1

Your regex `([0-9]+,\s+)` is close somehow to matching the input string but the comma has only one occurrence (you'd expect zero or more commas), and it should be followed by digits, not just whitespace.

Comment: Just posting the code is not as helpful. You should explain the problem with the OP's code

Comment: Unless the OP asks for a explanation.

Comment: @brso05 It's not just about the OP, questions at SO are supposed to be useful to others

Comment: Most people want an answer then they can look at the code themselves and figure out what is happening it's better to learn that way anyway then someone just telling you how to do something.

Comment: Reg. expressions are a very complex thing if someone wants to learn this isn't the place to learn.

Comment: @brso05 That's funny, I think the complexity is the reason you should explain why. I'm not saying telling them to do something. Just spitting code is telling them to do something.

Comment: @brso05 Point is not to explain every single detail about this regex (to teach its syntax, we assume that OP have some minimal knowledge about regex) but to explain main **idea** behind it. Something like "this regex matches `number` (represented by `\\d+`) and *zero or more of* `, number` (represented by `(,\\s*\\d+)*`) after it" will let others read this solution easier.

Comment: @brso05 - the more useful your answer is to others, the more likely you are to attract upvotes. By putting in more explanation, it makes your answer more useful to others. StackOverflow can be a great place to learn things - that's why we ask questions in the first place!

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `\(([0-9]+[\,]{1}[\s]*)+[0-9]+\)`

**Edit:** `\(([0-9]+[\,]{1}[\s]*)*[0-9]+\)` - also matches (1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could possibly help you.

```
(\(){1}(\d+,[ ]+)+(\)){1}
```

or with the leading and trailng /

```
/(\(){1}(\d+,[ ]+)+(\)){1}/
```

The method you tried ([0-9]+,\s+)
is saying that you can have as many digits as you would like, followed by a comma, followed by  white space. in your attempt did you account for multiple digits followed by commas, or the leading and trailing parenthesizes.